# Datetime format for a month and year

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DateTime ExpMonth = Convert.ToInt32(ddExpMonth); ---- DropDown(user selects a month)
DateTime ExpYear = Convert.ToInt32(ddExpYear);   ---- Dropdown(user selects year)

Datetime ExpDate = ///// I want this part to be saved as Datetime  02/2012
```

How is this possible. Or any other way.

Comment: Are you simply wanting to format the date for display or will you be doing date comparisons for an expiration date?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `DateTime` value doesn't know about a format - it's just a date and a time. You can create a new `DateTime` value with the relevant information:

```
DateTime expiry = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(ddExpYear),
                               Convert.ToInt32(ddExpMonth),
                               1);
```

... but how that is "saved" is entirely up to you. If you give us more information, we may be able to help you more. You can format it to a string easily enough:

```
string formatted = expiry.ToString("yyyy/MM");
```

... but that may not be what you're after.

Answer (score 4):

You could store it in a DateTime as follows:

```
DateTime expDate = new DateTime(ExpYear, ExpMonth, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

If it's for a credit card expiration date, make sure the day is the last day of the month or don't compare the day. Their may be some discrepancies on the last day being expired or not. It should be still valid so make sure the current date is at least a day greater.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save this value either as a `nvarchar`, where you'll be able to do whatever you want, or a `datetime`. The difference is that the `datetime` format requires you to provide the *day*, and the time be set to *midnight*. The value 1, for the first day of the month should be considered here.

Answer (score 0):

```
       DateTime Today = new DateTime( DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
       DateTime cc = new DateTime(2016, 9, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

        Console.WriteLine(Today.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(cc.ToString());


        if (Today <=  cc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Card Expiry Date is not valid ");
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please supply your answer with some context, as code-only answers do not fulfill SO standards: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer