# Convert string to MM/yyyy in c# to sort

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I have seen previous questions which are related my query but couldn't figure out on how to resolve my issue.

I have a list "Sites" with one of the items as "Year". It is defined as string and is in the format "MM/yyyy". When I try to sort the list based on the year, I'm facing a small problem.

Data for "Year" is

```
01/2012
04/2012
01/2013
06/2012
```

When I sort the list by using orderby, the output I'm getting is

```
01/2012
01/2013
04/2012
06/2012
```

which is incorrect.

Cannot convert the string using `Convert.ToDateTime` as the string format doesn't contain day value. How should I go forward with this? How to implement `DateTime.TryParseExact` without changing the format of the string?

Note : The format should be the same and the list should be sorted.

Comment: Use a constant 1 as the day value?  e.g. `DateTime.ParseExact("01/"+myDate,"dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: I cannot change the format of the output. It has to be in `MM/yyyy`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513727/datetime-format-for-a-month-and-year -- check this out

Comment: You don't have  to change the format of the output.  I was suggesting using that just to _sort_ the list.

Comment: Another suggestion. If you reversed all the dates temporarily as strings and then sorted. Then reverse back. That might work. Scratches head. 

Comment: However, both `Convert.ToDateTime` and `DateTime.Parse` both should accept `MM/yyyy` as a format - it will infer a day of 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could try something like this without having to change the input this will give you the order that you like also look at the `OrderByDescending` property if you need it in a different sort order

```
var dateList = new List<string> { "01/2012", "04/2012", "01/2013", "06/2012" };
var orderedList = dateList.OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: I hadn't realized that `DateTime.Parse()` would accept a date in that format. I left my answer anyway to show a more complex `Func` occurring within a LINQ lambda.

Comment: @krillgar I looked at your solution as well and it works really nice for someone who can understand a more complex Func I also gave it a `+1`

Answer (score 4):

You can still convert the string to a date within a LINQ statement, and the items will stay as strings.

```
var strings = new[]
{
    "01/2012",
    "04/2012",
    "01/2013",
    "06/2012"
};

var ordered = strings.OrderBy(s =>
{
    var split = s.Split('/');
    return new DateTime(int.Parse(split[1]), int.Parse(split[0]), 1);
});
```

Your last item will then be `"01/2013"`.

As MethodMan showed in his answer, `DateTime.Parse()` will be able to parse a `MM/yyyy` formatted dated. However, if you need to perform anything that takes more than one line, this would be how you can do that. **NB:** This will ***not*** work in any query against a DbContext!

Answer (score 0):

Implement System.IComparable interface:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    // Check null
    if (obj == null)
        return 1;

    // Check types
    if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot compare to different type.", "obj");

    // Extract year and month
    var year = int.Parse(this.Year.SubString(3, 4));
    var month = int.Parse(this.Year.SubString(0, 2));

    // Extract year and month to compare
    var site = (Sites)obj;
    var objyear = int.Parse(site.Year.SubString(3, 4));
    var objmonth = int.Parse(site.Year.SubString(0, 2));

    // Compare years first
    if (year != objyear)
        return year - objyear;

    // Same year

    // Compare months
    return month - objmonth;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you also can create a new list with Dates converted to DateTime format and sort it after. It's a lot of lines but good for learning.

```
    class Sites
    {
        public string Year { get; set; }
    }
    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<Sites> ListOfSites = new List<Sites>();
            ListOfSites.Add(new Sites { Year = "01/2012" });
            ListOfSites.Add(new Sites { Year = "04/2012" });
            ListOfSites.Add(new Sites { Year = "01/2013" });
            ListOfSites.Add(new Sites { Year = "06/2012" });

            DateTime SiteYear;
            List<DateTime> listWithDates = new List<DateTime>(); 

            foreach (var item in ListOfSites)
            {
                if(DateTime.TryParse(item.Year, out SiteYear))
                {
                    listWithDates.Add(SiteYear);
                }
            }
            Display(SortAscending(listWithDates), "Sort Ascending");

        }
        static List<DateTime> SortAscending(List<DateTime> list)
        {
            list.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
            return list;
        }
        static void Display(List<DateTime> list, string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            foreach (var datetime in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(datetime);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SergeVikisgenko  I know that there are many ways to skin a cat however you approach seem a bit `OverKill`

Comment: @MethodMan you might be right. I've used foreach loop and parse each element to a new list with DateTime format. In your case it's a lambda expression which is done with two lines of code. It depends what you trying to achieve. In your case your list is still string, mine is converted to DateTime format.

Comment: I would suggest learning Lambda it will make your life a lot easier and no need for any looping what so ever to solve this issue respectfully speaking

Comment: @MethodMan I'm working on it! :) I voted for your answer since it's shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: I appreciate that.. I am not downing your answer I am just saying that there are more efficient ways to get at the same answer i.e `Different ways to skin the same cat` Cheers..:)

Comment: Please provide an explanation for downvoting.